# Opera browser changes color of disabled textbox

Tags: javascript, forms, html, textbox

I have a text box and I am disabling it on a button click

My sample code is :

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");
inputBox.value='';
inputBox.disabled=true;
```

I opened my file in all browsers ( chrome , mozilla , opera ) and only opera is changing color for the disabled text box. Is there any way not to change the text box box to gray color or is it default property of opera?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of opera's behavior you can always style the disabled button -

```
[disabled]{ background: gray; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the default behavior of all browsers to change the color of a disabled box, ins't it? Your current CSS seems to be resetting the look of all other browsers. I guess Opera is the only one setting the background to gray.

Search for something like

```
input:disabled{
  /*.. Some CSS Code..*/
}
```

And change the backgrond to the desired color.

```
input:disabled{
  /*.. Some CSS Code..*/      
  // Change to white...
  background-color: #fff;
}
```